# How to set new value of the Angular directive "ng-init" depending on the value of a <select> dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

So I want to set a value for `ng-init` if a specific option is selected. If that specific option is not selected yet, or is changed away from, I'd like to delete the `ng-init` value.

```
<select id="exSelect" onchange="checkButton()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<textarea type="text"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="vm.request.description"
    name="description" id="description"
    rows="10" placeholder="Must be atleast 50 characters."
    ng-minlength="50"
    required>
</textarea>
```

```js
function checkButton()
{
    var dropdownValue = document.getElementById("exSelect");
    if (dropdownValue.value == "3") {
        //Why does this not work?
        document.getElementById("description").ng-init = 'Example attribute setting';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("description").ng-init = '';
    }
}
```

This code is super simplified example version of what I am working on right now, but overall a similar idea of what I am trying to do as a small part of a much larger program. So I would like for the `checkButton()` function to run each time a new option is selected. If 3 is selected, I would like the if statement to execute and set the "ng-init" attribute of the element with the Id of "description" as the text in the function. If another option is selected, I would like for the `checkButton()` function to run again and it will set the the `ng-init` attribute as empty.

Comment: Why do you want to set a `ng-init` when that happens? The goal you are trying to get can be fullfiled with any variable?

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong use of `ng-init`. I encourage you not to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First use the `ng-model` and `ng-change` directives:

```
<select id="exSelect" ng-model="vm.sel1" ng-change="vm.checkButton()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Then in your controller:

```
vm.checkButton = function() {
    if (vm.sel1 == "3") {
        vm.request.description = 'Example attribute setting';
    } else {
        vm.request.description =  = '';
    };
});
```